# Remove data from list when checkbox in unchecked

Tags: flutter, list, listview, checkbox

I used this command  `widgets.removeAt(data[index]['title']);` but when I tried to uncheck its checkbox not all titles of checkboxs are removed.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> widgets = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
    {'title': 'checkbox1', 'value': false},
    {'title': 'checkbox2', 'value': false},
    {'title': 'checkbox3', 'value': false}
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Column(children: widgets),
          ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(data[index]['title']),
                  value: data[index]['value'],
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      // bool check=data[index]['value'] = value!;
                      if (data[index]['value'] = value!) {
                        widgets.add(Text(data[index]['title'].toString()));
                        print(data[index]['title'].toString());
                      } else {
                        widgets.removeAt(index);
                      }
                    });
                  });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );  }
}
```

Screenshot here

[image]

In that picture checkbox title not removed;
in the console I got this error:

> Value not in range: 2

Comment: this error is happening because the index being accessed is out of range. 
simple fix is to use removeWhere method instead of removeAt:
widgets.removeWhere((widget) => widget is Text && widget.data == data[index]['title']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `List<Widget>` you can use list of String to hold items and then you can easily remove items,

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> checkedItem = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
    {'title': 'checkbox1', 'value': false},
    {'title': 'checkbox2', 'value': false},
    {'title': 'checkbox3', 'value': false}
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          // title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: checkedItem.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(data[index]['title']),
                  value: data[index]['value'],
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      // bool check=data[index]['value'] = value!;
                      if (data[index]['value'] = value!) {
                        checkedItem.add(data[index]['title'].toString());
                      } else {
                        checkedItem.remove(data[index]['title']);
                      }
                    });
                  });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```